# css3 size transform for iphone

Tags: ios, css, webkit, mootools, css-transitions

I have a `div` that needs to be re-sized to a determined value, let's say that it has to pass from a width of 320px to a width of 60px.

I used CSS `-webkit-transform`, so basically as I apply the new value to my div all is working smoothly. The only problem here is that I have to make it run on an iPhone.
I am aware of the 3D transform issue, and I know that I should use 3dscale instead, in order to make it work smooth, but using scale doesn't get me the pixel accuracy I'd need.
So, I was wondering if there would be any other method.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you instead used MooTools' tools for animation. It will not be as smooth as the accelerated transforms, but at least it will work in all modern browsers and be exact.

You should look into [Fx.Tween](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx.Tween) or [Fx.Morph](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx.Morph).

Comment: as it's mentioned in the tags I need to make it work smoothly *just* for ios I don't care about browsers, it's just ad app mock, it' not a website. thx anyway